# $\rho=\sqrt{\frac{R+j \omega L}{G+j \omega C}}$, find the condition to have $Re\{\rho\}\ge0$ and $Im\{\rho\}\ge0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

$$\rho=\sqrt{\frac{R+j \omega L}{G+j \omega C}} \qquad R,G \ge 0 \qquad \omega,L,C>0 $$

$$\rho=\sqrt{\frac{(R+j \omega L) \ (G-j \omega C)}{G^2+\omega^2C^2}}$$

$$\rho=\sqrt{\frac{RG+j \omega LG-j\omega RC+\omega^2 LC}{G^2+\omega^2C^2}}$$

$$0 \le \arctan\Big( \frac{\omega LG-\omega RC}{RG+\omega^2LC} \Big) \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The question does not make sense because there are two square roots for the ratio and $Re \rho >0$ for one square root implies $Re \rho <0$  for the other.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It does make some sense if we consider the question to be asking when "Re $\rho$ and Im $\rho$ have the same sign".

Comment: @CaveJohnson Agree, but $\sqrt z$ is not an accepted symbol for complex numbers and I think the OP should edit the question to say how exactly $\rho $ is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

$$
|\rho| = \sqrt{\frac{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}{C^2 \omega ^2+G^2}}
$$

and

$$
\angle \rho = \frac 12\arctan{\left(\frac{(GL-CR)\omega}{CL \omega^2+GR}\right)}
$$

then $\Re(\rho) \ge 0 $ and $\Im(\rho) \ge 0 $ implies on

$$
0 \le \frac 12\arctan{\left(\frac{(GL-CR)\omega}{CL \omega^2+GR}\right)}\le \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

NOTE

$$
z = \rho e^{i\phi}\to \sqrt z = \rho^{\frac 12} e^{\frac i2 \phi}
$$